# google play store says "check your connection and try again"

Tags: google-play-store

Yesterday I got a Xiaomi Redmi 1s and I updated the phone to the latest OS version.  First I created a new Google account and then opened the Play Store.  It just shows "Check Your Connection and Try Again".  Other sites said to try clearing the data, but I had never used the Play Store before.

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to access the Play Store previously with another device in the same network?  Have you tried different Wi-Fi networks?

Answer (score 16):

Hey I had the same problem but now I know how to fix it.  Set the device's date and time to Manual and 4 years in the future, then open the Play Store and you won't get anything.  Go back to settings and reset this to Automatic, then everything is okay!

Comment: This answer helped me. Except my phone was already not in automatic time mode. So, I checked the box to make the time automatically updated and opened the play store again and it worked!

Comment: I don't know whether to groan or laugh hysterically at the fact that this actually resolved the problem, so I think I'll do both. I started getting this message after clearing the Play Store app's data due to another problem, and this trick fixed it. How on Earth did you ever figure that out??

Comment: This actually worked and it also solved a 505 error I was getting when downloading an application. Thank you so much!

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: didnt work for me too. the /etc/hosts cleanup worked (at least temporarily)

Comment: Worked for me!  Manually set time, and google play (and automatic downloads) came back to life.  Android 2.3.6.

Comment: Worked for me on Samsung Galaxy S2 that has been powered off for several weeks.

Answer (score 4):

I usually resolve by removing /etc/hosts file (use an app like Root Explorer to access the file, Xiaomi phones are rooted OTB so you shouldn't have any problem). Sometimes I have to reboot the phone, sometimes it works straight away.

Better, instead of removing the file rename it to something else, so that you can restore it back if needed.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Cleaning the 'hosts' file helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanx Jeffrey, it works for me too :)

Comment: Thanks. pretty quick work. I didn't need a restart.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening more and more. If the time trick does not help, try to enter Google Maps (invoke something that makes heavy use of the Google Services API) and try Google Play again - this has fixed it for me in the past.